# What is the word for someone who is up for everything?

Tags: word-request

I need an adjective that describes a person who is always up for every offer. For example:

A: Who's up for going to the cinema?

B: me!

A: Who's up for pizza?

B:me!

A:I'm going to Paris tomorrow, who would like to join me?

B:me!

---

**Person B is called a --- person?**

Comment: Have you tried your bilingual dictionary?

Comment: “Eager beaver” is an informal possibility. While it does have a sense of “eager to work” (and that certainly was its original meaning) it can certainly be extended to “eager to enjoy activities”. For example, the Merriam-Webster dictionary has the example sentence, *The show starts just before 10 p.m., but eager beavers usually begin arriving downtown in early afternoon to seek out a prime viewing spot.*